# onCreate doesn't run in a service

Tags: android

I'm writing this service but I can't see the log strings when I launch the app.
if I put a Log.i in the method startBeaconDetecting I can see it but after the onCreate() method doesn't start.
Why onCreate doesn't run?

```
public class ProximityBeacon extends Service
{
    private String server;
    private String ID;


    public ProximityBeacon(String server)
    {
        this.server=server;
        //TODO indirizzo del server
    }

    public void startBeaconDetecting(String ID, Intent intent, Context context)
    {
        this.ID=ID;
        context.startService(intent);
       }

    public void stopBeaconDetecting()
    {
        stopSelf();
        onDestroy();
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Oncreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand"); 
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you registered this service in AndroidManifest.xml??

Comment: <service
            android:name=".ProximityBeacon"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

Comment: So on startService(service) , onStartCommand  will run.

Comment: the code in the manifest was already written, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523227/4519859  ,it is working for me so it should be working for you as well.

Comment: post the code where you start the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Service class to this:

```
public class ProximityBeacon extends Service
{
    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private String server;
    private String ID;

    public ProximityBeacon() {
    }

    public ProximityBeacon(String server)
    {
        this.server=server;
        //TODO indirizzo del server
    }

    public void startBeaconDetecting(String ID, Intent intent, Context context)
    {
        this.ID=ID;
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    public void stopBeaconDetecting()
    {
        stopSelf();
        onDestroy();
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "ProximityBeacon Oncreate");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "ProximityBeaconon StartCommand");
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and then call it using this:

```
new ProximityBeacon("").startBeaconDetecting("" ,new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProximityBeacon.class) ,mContext) ;
```

then add it in manifest.xml like this :

```
<service android:name=".services.ProximityBeacon" />
```

Output : 19:25:11.873 23002-23002/com.sample.service I/TAG: ProximityBeaconon StartCommand

Answer (score 0):

after startService(service); will run onStartCommand, not onCreate

Comment: try to start service via
startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Service.class));